# Partial MySQL index from End of Field

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, field, partial

A partial index helps to have smaller indexes, and makes INSERTs faster.

For instance

```
  CREATE TABLE wine (
    name VARCHAR(100),
    ...
    INDEX (name(8)));
```

While names are something like

```
  Chateau Mouton-Rothschild
  Chateau Mouton-Cadet
  Chateau Petrus
  Chateau Lafite
  Chateau Lafleur
  ...
```

In this (example) list, `Chateau` appears all the time, MySQL creates an index based on the 8 first characters... meaning there will be only one entry in the index (and the search of `Chateau Petrus` will be done sequentially for all `Chateau`).
(In this very case, a split between the first word (`Chateau`) and the rest of the name in two fields would make sense, but this is not the point).

Is there a way to ask MySQL to create a partial index based on the *end* of a field?

Comment: very good question, I'm waiting for the answer.

Comment: No, MySQL (unlike many other DBMS) does not support this kind of advanced indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a way in the meantime - with a bit of programming:

Only for the `name` field

- all `name` entries are stored *reverse* in the DB
- all `name` searches are made *reverse*
- `name` in row is *reversed* before being sent to client (user agent)

For instance in PHP

- `...query('INSERT ... name="' . strrev($name) . '"...`
- `...query('SELECT * FROM wine WHERE name="' . strrev($name) . '"');`
- and for instance a search of `%MOUTON%` will actually search `%NOTUOM%`

There is a bit of `reverse` overhead, but is negligible compared to the possible database gain.

The question was specifically asking for a pure MySQL solution, but if there is none, this is a workable workaround in any language. I'll accept this answer in a few days if there is nothing better.

Comment: Note that queries of the form `LIKE %FOO%` don't use indexes in MySQL. The DB will scan all candidate rows and perform the comparison for each row. Given that, the gain here is negligible and probably not worth the extra complexity.

Comment: Yes but following my *reverse* algorithm, a search of `%MOUTON%` wouldn't return the right rows... it's mentioned to make the answer clearer

Comment: I'm suggesting that reversing the data you insert into the database probably isn't worth the extra complexity _unless_ there's a large amount of data at the beginning of each field you want to ignore.

Comment: @Michael Exactly. The *reverse* overhead is actually not that bad. Access to the DB goes through an interface (meaning external modules do not need to know something is reversed) and we can easily map reversed fields in a constant array to identify and process them accurately. An example of fields, besides wine, could be phone numbers from the world, where a lot of common prefixes exist - and we don't want to create yet another column for phone number prefixes... (the end of the number is actually distributed more randomly)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the solution you mentioned above, the only solution for this in MySQL is to explicitly store the value you want to index. (e.g. `name` without `Chateau`)

Comment: Yes indeed, it applies to my specific example in this case - this is why I mentioned in the question that this is just an example and a split of words is not the point...

Comment: @ring0 This isn't specific to splitting words. I'm suggesting that if you want to index whatever you consider the "end" of a field, you would have to store that in a separate column.

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear, this is what *a split between the first word (Chateau) and the rest of the name in two fields* implied.